# How to add a column after the last column containing a certain string?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a dataset like this

```
df <- data.frame(abc_1 = 1:10, abc_2 = 11:20, abc_3 = 21:30, somevar = 31:40)
head(df)
   abc_1 abc_2 abc_3 somevar
1      1    11    21      31
2      2    12    22      32
3      3    13    23      33
4      4    14    24      34
5      5    15    25      35
6      6    16    26      36
```

I would like to insert a new column after abc_3 (in my case the row sums of abc_1, abc_2, abc_3). Since (a) the dataset is huge, (b) I might decide to manipulate the dataset before adding the column (i.e. messing up the column indices), and since (c) I would like to do this for many variables that contain some different string, I am looking to use a way of doing this without referencing the column index but rather by matching the string abc.

I have found add_column in the tibble package but it only allows adding the column by its index like so

```
library(tibble)
add_column(df, abc_sum = rowSum(abc_1, abc_2, abc_3), .after = 3)
```

What I want is something like this:

```
   abc_1 abc_2 abc_3 abc_sum somevar
1      1    11    21      33      31
2      2    12    22      36      32
3      3    13    23      39      33
4      4    14    24      42      34
5      5    15    25      45      35
6      6    16    26      48      36
```

I am looking to replace the `.after = 3` with an expression that inserts it after abc_3 by matching the string abc_3.

Comment: If you can add `an example output`, that might lead to higher chances of getting the result (& quicker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
add_column(df, 
           abc_sum = rowSums(df[startsWith(names(df), "abc")]),
           .after = "abc_3")

   abc_1 abc_2 abc_3 abc_sum somevar
1      1    11    21      33      31
2      2    12    22      36      32
3      3    13    23      39      33
4      4    14    24      42      34
5      5    15    25      45      35
6      6    16    26      48      36
7      7    17    27      51      37
8      8    18    28      54      38
9      9    19    29      57      39
10    10    20    30      60      40
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `reduce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    mutate(abc_sum = select(., starts_with('abc')) %>%
        reduce(`+`)) %>%
    select(starts_with('abc'), everything())
#   abc_1 abc_2 abc_3 abc_sum somevar
#1      1    11    21      33      31
#2      2    12    22      36      32
#3      3    13    23      39      33
#4      4    14    24      42      34
#5      5    15    25      45      35
#6      6    16    26      48      36
#7      7    17    27      51      37
#8      8    18    28      54      38
#9      9    19    29      57      39
#10    10    20    30      60      40
```